# Reusing a variable name as for loop index doesn't produce the error I expect

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, scope

Am I allowed to re-use the same variable name in different `for` loops in Objective-C? For example:

```
// This doesn't give me an error but I feel like it should:

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //do something
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){    // I'm using "i" again.  Is this allowed?
    //do something else
}
```

This compiles and seems to run fine, but I just want to make sure that this is legal and allowed without causing some sort of complication in my program. I'm newish to ObjC, but in Java I normally would get errors from this.

Comment: That code is perfectly fine in java as well..

Comment: Its been a while but I recall getting errors often when reusing variable names for iteration variables in for loops.

Comment: I just tested it with a sample .java file and javac on mac os, no problems here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be fine. The scope of `i` in the snippet you show is limited to each of the `for` loops, so there's no conflict. If you instead do it like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    //...
}

int i;
for (i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    //...
}
```

then you'll have a problem because you're declaring `i` twice in the same scope.

Comment: Okay perfect.  I am not declaring i beforehand so my scopes should be good.  Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine. Because you doesn't initialize the integer outside of the for loop. If you had two times this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; ...)
```

then you would of course get a compile error, because you can't define two variables with the same name in the same block.